# Revert Database changes on Jakarta EE Batch failure

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, batch-processing, jsr352

I am developing a `Jakarta EE` Batch using `EclipseLink` and `Wildfly`. I am stuck at the `ItemWriter` level. The Writer basically creates a file and should write some records into it. Each file is associated with a `Delivery` which is my entity. So one file per delivery. The delivery numbers should increase ascendingly.

Here is the relevant part of the entity that im using:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "DELIVERY")
public class Delivery {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "lieferung_id_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "lieferung_id_generator", sequenceName = "lieferung_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "DELIVERY_NO", nullable = false)
    private Long deliveryNo;

    @Column(name = "DELIVERY_DATE", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate deliveryDate;

    @Column(name = "FILENAME", nullable = false)
    private String deliveryFile;
```

Here is the writer:

```java
@Named
@Dependent
public class MyItemWriter extends TypedItemWriter<List<String>, Serializable> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = MyPersistenceUnit.NAME)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private FileWriter fileWriter;
    private Delivery newDelivery;
    private Integer writtenRecords;

    @Override
    protected void doOpen(Serializable checkpoint) {
        if (checkpoint == null) {
            File deliveryFile = new File(erzeugeDateiName());
            newDelivery = persistNewLieferung(dateiZurLieferung);
            writtenRecords = 0;

            try {
                boolean isFileCreated = deliveryFile.createNewFile();
                if (!isFileCreated) {
                    throw new BatchRuntimeException("File already exists.");
                }
                fileWriter = new FileWriter(deliveryFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new BatchRuntimeException("Error upon file creation: {}", e);
            }

            // Initial Filewriting without Records from `ItemProcessor`
            // [...]
        } else {
            writtenRecords = (Integer)checkpoint;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doWriteItems(List<List<String>> items) {
        for (List<String> records: items) {
            records.forEach(this::writeToFile);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Serializable doCheckpointInfo() {
        return writtenRecords;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        Delivery previousDelivery = getPreviousDelivery();
        writeToFile(createRecord(newDelivery.getDeliveryNo().toString(),
                                 writtenRecords,
                                 previousDelivery.getDeliveryDate(),
                                 previousDelivery.getDeliveryNo().toString()));                                              
        fileWriter.close();
    }
```

1. In `doOpen()` I create a new `Delivery` and persist it. The delivery number `deliveryNo` is the primary key and gets assigned by the database when I persist the new delivery.
2. Afterwards all the records coming from my `ItemProcessor` get written to the file.
3. In `close()` I need to write one more record thats different from the others. In this record I need information about the new and the previous delivery (to be precise, I need their `deliveryNo` and `deliveryDate`).

### The problem

When an exception occurs during the batch job (e.g. `IOException`, the new delivery is a failure but still...

- it gets persisted
- the sequence that manages the `deliveryNo`s is therefore increased nonetheless.
- the content of the special record that im writing in `close()` points to a failed delivery which is a critical error state and must be prevented. **Ideally, there should only be successful deliveries in the database**.

Now my question is: How can I prevent the failed delivery to be persisted and the `deliveryNo` counter to be increased when the batch job fails? Is there an easy / non-hacky way to "revert" everything so the database is basically in the state from before the batch job's execution? Is this even possible?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your case. Can you handle any failed delivery in your item processor class? If it detects any error in any instance of delivery, the item processor's process method can just return null to filter it out, plus some application-specific handling.

Comment: The ItemProcessor does its job just fine, the problem really is the ItemWriter where the file-writing stuff happens.

Comment: Sequencing is meant to be outside the transaction, so the same sequence object can be used by many transactions concurrently. If it is incremented, it should not be decremented with a rollback or there is something wrong. From the sounds of things, you are getting an error in the file writing portion, but have done this separately and outside of the transaction that writes your delivery entity. Either have it done in the same transactional scope (you didn't show any transaction info) so it auto rollback on error, or write the file first then persist the delivery entity.

Comment: I already thought about deleting the entity and decrease the sequence again but as you said thats not what should be done generally. I think im just going to move the persisting part to a place where the writing stuff is already finished. But out of interest, how would i do it in the same transactional scope? Im using `persistence.xml` with `JTA` transaction type. I basically just inject my `entityManager` where i need it. I think i dont even have control of the transactions because of transaction-type = JTA.

Comment: You still define the transactional scope: Wrap your doOpen in a transactional context and have the persistence layer use that transaction instead of starting a new one. As for cleanup - decrementing the sequence shouldn't be done, but you can delete an entity at any point. Your error handling is going to need to handle issues that arise even on close, and decide what to do with the partial file and previous/new delivery instances. Anything from file errors to network/db errors can occur at any point and cause data to be left in an invalid state.

Comment: I'm confused about the use case and how it fits with the basic fact that the batch container executes chunks within a global transaction.    So, without either your application catching or handling exceptions, or without using the skip/retry function built into the batch API, it would seem like your DB updates would indeed get rolled back along with the batch-managed chunk transaction.   Are you using these?   It looks like you may be doing persistence from close() which can be confusing since this should be part of the marked-for-rollback tran.   What code is throwing the exception here?

Comment: I dont have much experience with JEE or JSR-352 but i am persisting the new delivery right in `doOpen()` by using `entityManager.persist()`.  Right now there are no exceptions but exceptions could be thrown e.g. if the file already exists. Exceptions can occur in `doOpen()`, `doWriteItems()` and in `close()`. If an exception occurs during the batch the `Delivery` is persisted though, so i cannot see anyhing rollbacked, yet.

Comment: It would be ideal if there was a way to commit the database stuff only once the batch is done and no exceptions can occur anymore, but i dont know if that is possible.

Comment: Sorry, missed your comment until now.   I'm not 100% sure I'm understanding your scenario correctly, but one issue I see is that while open() and close() will each run under a global transaction (per specification), this will NOT be the same global transaction as the one that the chunk will be executed within (i.e. not the tran that writeItems() will execute under).   If you wanted an error during writeItems to rollback a DB insert, then you should move the DB insert logic to the writeItems() method.   Since you have the full list of records for the chunk you can still do a batch update.